# Accessing IAuthSession in non-controller classes in ServiceStack/MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I am new to ServiceStack, so this is probably a noob question:

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC4 application that uses ServiceStack and am trying to figure out how I could get a hold of the current IAuthSession from within a class (either a EF context or a PetaPoco Database) used by my MVC4 controllers derived from ServiceStackController.

The class in question is registered with Funq with the ReuseScope.Request scope (i.e. on the per-HTTP request basis), and ideally I'd like every instance of it to be autowired with the current IAuthSession using either a constructor parameter or a public property.

How do I do that?

---

**UPDATE**

After some digging I came up with what I think might work.

In my `AppHost.Configure` I register a lambda that returns a session from the current request:

```
container.Register<IAuthSession>(c =>
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ToRequest().GetSession());
```

Also:

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<EFCatalogDb>();
```

where `EFCatalogDb` is my EF context that takes `IAuthSession` as a constructor argument:

```
public class EFCatalogDb : DbContext
{
    public EFCatalogDb(IAuthSession session) : base()
    { }
    // ...etc....
}
```

Unfortunately I am not at the point in my development when I can test this workaround, so have to ask others if it makes sense at all.

Comment: Found something that sounds pretty similar to what I'm trying to do but no real answer there:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/jnX8UwRWN8A

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to try to keep IAuthSession out of your database classes since that creates a dependency on ServiceStack that seems unnecessary.

That being said, I think you could go the route of registering IAuthSession and having the container automatically inject IAuthSession. A better way might be creating your own 'wrapper class' around IAuthSession and injecting that into your database classes. That would then break the dependency on ServiceStack.

If you have no issue keeping a dependency on ServiceStack another possibility would be using the `SessionFeature` class and doing something like

```
var key = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey();
authSession = AppHost.Resolve<ICacheClient>().Get<IAuthSession>(key);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know such functionality existed in SessionFeature.

I don't mind having an extra dependency on ServiceStack in my DAL because I already use it for logging.

Comment: When I tried to implement your suggestion I got this:

`System.NotImplementedException: Only ASP.NET Requests accessible via Singletons are supported`.  

It errors out because `SessionFeature.GetSessionId()` needs either an `IHttpRequest` wrapper or `HttpContext.Current`, and the latter for some reason is null despite the fact that I am using `JsonServiceClient` to call my service.

Any idea why my `HttpContext` is missing?

Comment: Maybe you need to add the SessionFeature Plugin - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions